# CSS3 custom animation triggering after :hover

Tags: css, animation, hover

I'm creating a series of "windows" or "doggie doors" that, when hovered on, seem to push back into the "window" just like a doggie door.

I've been able to create a natural looking effect of the doggie door closing.  It swings back and forth a couple times and then rests back to its default position.

My problem is that I haven't been able to figure out a way to trigger the swing when the hover is released.  I know its a logic issue because I've seen examples of it done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e4FMm/) and using keyframes [here][2].  I also know I could solve this with javascript but I'm sticking strictly to CSS for this site.

UPDATE:

Here is the working example. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4FMm/)

Thank you Nobita!

HTML:

```
<ul class="window">
    <li>
        <figure class="door">
            <img src="http://www.ta-sa.org/data/images/laughing_man_big_2.png" alt="">
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    list-style: none;



}
.door {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    perspective:1000px;
    -webkit-perspective:1000px;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
}
.door img {
    background-color: #E8585A;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    transform-origin: top;
    -ms-transform-origin: top;
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-animation: swing 2s;
    -webkit-animation: swing 2s;
    animation: swing 2s;
    z-index: 10;
}

.door:hover img {
      transform-origin: top;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-60deg);
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    background-color: #00a99d;
    -webkit-animation: swing;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
}
@-webkit-keyframes swing {
    0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    }
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-60deg);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-60deg);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(25deg);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-20deg);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(5deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't trigger anything when the hover is released with just `css`

Comment: This guy did it.
http://css-tricks.com/examples/DifferentTransitionsOnOff/

Comment: That is the animation going back to it's default position, so yes you could try and fake it, but you can't call a custom animation on a "`mouseleave`" event with `css`

Comment: Right, thats why it's been titled 'animation triggering after :hover'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice technique, I didn't know you could trigger animations when hovering off a div!
I fiddled a bit and hopefully got it working even if not as smoothly as expected, but it's probably enough to take a step further in the right direction.

The problem here is - I guess - that you're not declaring an animation on hover state (as suggested in your links), but just a transition. So I tried adding a transition for the 'door' to open on hover...

```
.door:hover img {
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotateX(-60deg);
  transition: all .2s;
```

...and an animation which will fire on mouseout:

```
   animation: swing;
 }
```

Hope this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/Jc6LU/5/) shows what you need or at least helps you someway. 
Anyway very glad myself to have learnt something new, thanks.

```css
* {
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
 
}
*:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
.door {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    perspective:1000px;
    -webkit-perspective:1000px;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
}
.door img {
    background-color: #E8585A;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    transform-origin: top;
    -ms-transform-origin: top;
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-animation: swing 2s;
    -webkit-animation: swing 2s;
    animation: swing 2s;
    z-index: 10;
}

.door:hover img {
      transform-origin: top;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-60deg);
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    background-color: #00a99d;
    -webkit-animation: swing;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
}
@-webkit-keyframes swing {
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-60deg);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(25deg);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-20deg);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(5deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="window">
    <li>
        <figure class="door">
            <img src="https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png" alt="">
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thats a HUGE step in the right direction.

I'll update after tweaking it a bit.

Answer (score 4):

I got it working in Firefox v22 using the [:not pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Jc6LU/8/)**

```
.door img:not(:hover) {
    transform-origin: top;
    animation: swing 2s;
}
```

This pseudo class combination looks like a bad hack, but it works.

The animation still needs some work for -webkit- browsers...